# Easy way to remove escaped sequences from web / javascript content

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am using python `scrapy` module scraping a web page and got the following response:

```
if (typeof addMoreNewsResults == \'function\') { \r\n
    addMoreNewsResults( {\r\n\t\tblob: \'3DP.AX\',\r\n        
    sortBy: \'date\',\r\n        
    dateRange: \'all\',\r\n        
    totalResultNumber: 2,\r\n        
    totalResultNumberStr: "2",\r\n        
    news: [ \r\n    ]} ); \r\n    }
```

There are lots of escaped sequences there. I want to remove all of them like `\'` `\r`. I am wondering there should be some easy to use package to remove those sequences but was unable to find one. Any recommendation?

---

Update: Instead of regex or manually replace, I want some recommendations of more powerful package to do this. I think this is a pretty common task and should be some packages have this function:P

Comment: `text = re.sub("\r*\n*\'*\"*\t*", "", text)` for the characters in your example text

Answer (score 0):

You can use searching and replacing with regex.